How to interpret the requirement for danger in the definition of manslaughter?

In the UK, unlawful act manslaughter requires the defendant to:
(a) do an unlawful act;
(b) that is dangerous; and
(c) which causes the victim’s death.

My question relates to requirement b on dangerousness.
The test for dangerousness is entirely objective and so is based on the reasonable person would recognise that the other person would be subject to at least some form of harm.
But does this need to apply to the specific victim?
For example: if the offender acts dangerously because they know individual A is at risk of harm, does it still meet the requirement of dangerousness if individual A is fine but individual B suffers that harm (where this danger was completely unforeseen).
I can see arguments both ways. On the one hand, the act was clearly dangerous (to the legally untrained eye) as A was at risk of harm. But since the danger to B was completely unforeseen, perhaps this doesn't meet the legal requirement for danger.
I would appreciate any guidance here.

The unlawful act can be directed at someone other than the person who dies. As to dangerousness, it's not necessary to show that the specific chain of events that happened were reasonably foreseeable, but only that the acts were of a nature that a reasonable observer would regard them as likely to cause harm to somebody.
An example is the Court of Appeal's judgment in R v Mitchell [1983] QB 741, 2 WLR 938. Ronald Mitchell was queuing in a post office and argued with another customer, punching him so that he fell against an 89-year-old woman, who broke her leg. She died in hospital a week later of a pulmonary embolism related to the fracture. Mitchell was charged with unlawful act manslaughter, and contended in his defense that his dangerous unlawful act was directed against a different person and therefore did not fit the criteria. The appeal court decided that once he had committed the act, he was responsible for the events he had set in motion, although he had not intended to do any harm to the actual victim. An objective and reasonable observer would recognize that the act was of  a nature that some harm would result, even if the specific character of the harm could not be predicted.
The court referred to an earlier case in the House of Lords, DPP v Newbury and Jones [1977] AC 500, dealing with two people who had dropped a paving slab from a railway bridge and killed a member of the train crew. Their conviction for manslaughter was upheld because "sober and reasonable people" would realize that the act was dangerous to somebody, and it was not necessary to show that the defendants foresaw the danger to the actual victim (who, in the event, they had never even seen).
Both cases were cited in the House of Lords decision Attorney General's Reference No. 3 of 1994  [1998] AC 245, which was about an assault on a pregnant woman, which led to her child being born prematurely 17 days later, and then dying 121 days after that. The man who stabbed her was acquitted of both murder and manslaughter since the trial judge considered that at the time of the attack, the foetus was not "a person in being". The case was referred to  the Court of Appeal and then to the Lords as it raised an important point of law. Regarding the unlawful act manslaughter angle, Lord Mustill concluded:

[T]he proposition involves that manslaughter can be established against someone who does any wrongful act leading to death, in circumstances where it was foreseeable that it might hurt anyone at all; and that this is so even if the victim does not fall into any category of persons whom a reasonable person in the position of the defendant might have envisaged as being within the area of potential risk. This is strong doctrine, [but...] this is the present state of English law.

And Lord Hope:

Dangerousness in this context is not a high standard. All it requires is that it was an act which was likely to injure another person. As "injury" in this sense means "harm", the other person must also be a living person. [...] But in this case injury to another living person - the child's mother - was the inevitable result of the defendant's deliberate and unlawful act. Such was the character of the mens rea which the defendant possessed when he committed the initial act in the series of events which resulted in the death of the child.


[...] [I]t is unnecessary to prove that he knew that his act was likely to injure the person who died as a result of it. All that need be proved is that he intentionally did what he did, that the death was caused by it and that, applying an objective test, all sober and reasonable people would recognise the risk that some harm would result.

The Lords rejected the application of this idea to murder. Despite some older cases - such as R v Saunders (1573) 2 Plowd 473 in which a man tried to poison his wife with arsenic, but accidentally killed his daughter and was convicted of murder - the law had moved on in that regard.
